# How to make every worker role instance run cmd script?

Tags: azure

I want to run a cmd script on every worker role instance.
So I create a WCF service on each work role.
But I only get VIP. 
How can I use internal IP and open each endpoint and run the cmd script on each instance?
Does anybody have some suggestion on this?
Or use other way?

Comment: When do you want to run the cmd script?   On startup only or whenever something needs to happen?    Why are you using a WCF Service?

Comment: This should work http://stackoverflow.com/a/14496210/57428

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run cmd script at startup...you can use startup task in csdef for the purpose...this will ensure the cmd script is run on each instance. Some startup task may require elevated permissions to run...also configure start task type accordingly...as it may add to your deployment time if sequential in nature.

If for some reason this is not applicable to your needs, you can explore InstanceInputEndpoint which can give you handle to specific VM instance.